# POST to Google Oauth2 very slow

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth

I'm currently doing a WebClient.UploadValues() to the following URL:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

The issue that I am running into, is that the POST to the above URL is taking 20+ seconds to execute and provide a response. I've tried two different methods (via C#) of posting to the URL with a few parameters, but both methods take equally the same amount of time

Any suggestions/ideas? Example code below:

```
postData.Add("code", code);
postData.Add("client_id", GetAppID());
postData.Add("client_secret", GetAppSecret());
postData.Add("redirect_uri", GetRedirectURL(redirectUrl));
postData.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
string TokenResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
    WebClient.UploadValues(
        "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "POST",
        postData));
```

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. Does this happen on every request or does the speed fluctuate?